# bash: read stdin line by line with custom line delimiter

Tags: bash, readfile

I have a bash script that reads lines from stdin.

```
while read var
do
    echo $var
done
```

Now, I have to modify this so I could accept input with line delimiter "EndOfMessage" (delimiter of several symbols).

How could I do that?

Comment: I think the only way to achieve it is to pipe the input through _tr "\036" "\n"_ or a alike, if your records can themselves have '\n' you'll need some aliasing like _tr "\036\n" "\n\036"_.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this right, the input will be something like "line1EndOfMessageline2EndOfMessageline3"?  If so, you can do it like this:

```
sed $'s/EndOfMessage/\\\n/g' | while read var; do
    echo $var
done
```